# Cant push another view with Get.to in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a screen Notification containing item list, when i click one item, it push to detail page (using `Get.toNamed(routeName)`).
In detail page, i have two button, button A to show dialog, in dialog view i have a button using Get.back() to pop dialog. After pop dialog, i will press button B to pop detail page.
After that, it pop to Notification page and then i click a item in a list, it dont push to detail page. I was debug and i know that detail page route is still there, it dont pop (but detail view is still pop).
When i change `Get.toNamed(routeName)` to `Navigator.of(context).push`, it working good. So anyone else tell me the reason? 
Im not good in english, sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it by setting the property `preventDuplicates` to `false`.

```
Get.toNamed(
   routeName,
   preventDuplicates: false,
);
```

By default, the `GetX` package prevents pushing the same page onto the navigation stack multiple times.

Making the above change will allow you to navigate to the detail page as expected after closing the dialog and popping the detail page.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but when set preventDuplicates: false, it will duplicate detail route right? Because when back to list notfication page, detail route is still there.

Comment: Yes, adding it will allow duplicate copies of same screen. Rest everything will stay the same as before.